# How to connect to external oracle database from BSD

Tags: oracle, freebsd

One of my work mates has set up a freenas server for storage (version9.1)

I have created a jail under this running FreeBSD 10.3-STABLE.
I want to create a web server in this jail and need to be able to connect to an external oracle (11g) database. I have the web server working but have been unable to find information on how to connect to an external oracle server from freebsd.

Is this even possible?
I am very new to BSD and Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The Ports collection contains several oracle clients/odbc drivers etc. in the databases category

Comment: Hi - Thanks, I didn't know about the ports collection. I had a look. There looks like instant client 10. - "linux-oracle-instantclient-basic-10.2.0.3.20061115_5". I'll see if this works for freebsd and oracle 11 db's